# Styling buttons with width inside container

Tags: html, css

Take a look at http://crashjapan.net - in the sidebar, the Subscribe button (submit element) is staying inside its box, nicely centered, but the three buttons under "I want to help!" (link elements styled like buttons) are too wide. I have looked through the CSS but I can't figure out what is different and what to do to fix it. Can someone else spot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#secondary .widget .button {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0 10% 5px 10%;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is one possible solution.

Comment: This worked! I guess that the box-sizing (an attribute I had never heard of before) implicitly defaults to border-box for submit buttons but not for links that have been styled to look like buttons. Hence I did not see the difference in the actual CSS statements in Firebug. Thanks!

Comment: I encounter the need for `box-sizing` attribute so often, I couldn't help but try it first. Default style-sheets for various browsers have it different and all set up for all form elements; I've just checked for Chrome 44.0.2403.130, and as stated by you - the user agent stylesheet has `box-sizing: border-box;` for `input[type="submit"]`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that now. I didn't write the lion's share of the CSS - I am working with a small file called after the big one (a child theme, for those who know Wordpress), and `box-sizing:border-box` is in the parent file's reset for buttons and form fields. I'll add it for `a.button` and perhaps other things - I read up on `box-sizing`, and `border-box` is definitely more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
margin: 0 10% 5px 10%;
```

from this in your style.css:

```
#secondary .widget .button {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0 10% 5px 10%;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit Your class:

```
#secondary .widget .button {
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 78%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your button  #secondary .widget .button
to this:

## secondary .widget .button

```
{     
     color: #FFF;
     font-size: 1.2em;
     margin: 6px 0% 0px -5px !important; 
     margin-top: 0px;                     
     margin-right: 0%;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
     width: 70%;
}
```

6px will leave some space between those buttons.
width 70% will be also play a role for the margin.
You can try to play the width a bit to see how it looks like.